# Style html5 audio player

Tags: html, css, audio

The change i want is `border-radius:0px`

I try:

```html
<audio id="player" controls>
    <!--<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">-->
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

```css
#player {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

With no effect.

Any advice would be usefull.

Comment: The Audio player isn't affected by border-radius. The user-agent stylesheets don't style it that way. You will have to write your own audio player in HTML and JavaScript. Look into [this article on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player).

Comment: Ok, i understand.
I have no much time to make it, but i will do after my holidays (vacations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-radius: 0px` works perfectly in Firefox.
But it seems not effective in chrome. Use below to somewhat reduce the radius.

```css
#player{
background-color: #f1f3f4;
}
```

I mean change the background same as player background.